# Scala collection of elements accessible by name

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have some Scala code roughly analogous to this:

```
object Foo {
    val thingA = ...
    val thingB = ...
    val thingC = ...
    val thingD = ...
    val thingE = ...

    val thingsOfAKind = List(thingA, thingC, thingE)
    val thingsOfADifferentKind = List(thingB, thingD)
    val allThings = thingsOfAKind ::: thingsOfADifferentKind
}
```

Is there some nicer way of declaring a bunch of things and being able to access them both individually by name and collectively?

The issue I have with the code above is that the real version has almost 30 different things, and there's no way to actually ensure that each new thing I add is also added to an appropriate list (or that allThings doesn't end up with duplicates, although that's relatively easy to fix).

The various things are able to be treated in aggregate by almost all of the code base, but there are a few places and a couple of things where the individual identity matters.

I thought about just using a Map, but then the compiler looses the ability to check that the individual things being looked up actually exist (and I have to either wrap code to handle a failed lookup around every attempt, or ignore the problem and effectively risk null pointer exceptions).

I could make the kind each thing belongs to an observable property of the things, then I would at least have a single list of all things and could get lists of each of the kinds with filter, but the core issue remains that I would ideally like to be able to declare that a thing exists, has a name (identifier), and is part of a collection.

What I effectively want is something like a compile-time Map. Is there a good way of achieving something like this in Scala?

Comment: Can you mix in a trait that would add the `thingA` to a global registry of the right kind? `val thingA = new ... with Registry` where `trait Registry { Registry.thingsOfAKind += this }`.

Comment: >(and I have to either wrap code to handle a failed lookup around every attempt, or ignore the problem and effectively risk null pointer exceptions).< Use assertions for this.

Comment: An assertion will, at runtime, kill the program if an assumption turns out to be false. A null pointer exception will, at runtime, kill the program if an assumption turns out to be false. Using one to prevent the other only gains me a nicer error report, surely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this type of pattern?

```
class Things[A] {
  var all: List[A] = Nil
  def ->: (x: A): A = { all = x :: all; x }
}

object Test {
  val things1 = new Things[String]
  val things2 = new Things[String]

  val thingA = "A" ->: things1
  val thingB = "B" ->: things2
  val thingC = "C" ->: things1
  val thingD = ("D" ->: things1) ->: things2
}
```

You could also add a little sugar, making `Things` automatically convertible to `List`,

```
object Things {
  implicit def thingsToList[A](things: Things[A]): List[A] = things.all
}
```

I can't think of a way to do this without the `var` that has equally nice syntax.

Comment: Not wild about the var, but yeah, I should be able to do this and keep the mutability under wraps.

Comment: You can replace the var with a `val all = collection.mutable.Buffer[A]()` and then `def ->: (x: A): A = { all += x; x }`, or something like this.

Comment: I meant, I can't see a way to do it without mutability. My preference would be to either use `var`, or make sure the mutable collection (`Buffer`) doesn't leak outside the class.

Comment: Yes, I would like a solution that maintains the external appearance that the object I'm creating (which has both named members and collections of its members) is immutable. If I can use a var during initialisation but only expose a val, that's fine, and I can see how you could do that with this approach. Cheers!